# How can I remove a carpet stamp?

Tags: carpet, railing

I am not really sure what to call this, so for right now I am just calling it a carpet stamp. But really it's an indentation that was made by some sturdy iron railing fixed on to my living room floor. I guess it's the same thing as if you had a piece of furniture sitting on your carpet for ages and it made a really deep indentation.

[image: Stamp from Iron Railing]

Is there any way I can fix this area of carpet? I'd like to get it elevated back to the same height as the rest of the carpet.

Comment: How long ago was the railing removed? These indentations typically resolve themselves over time (a few weeks).

Comment: Removed it last night (8 hours ago).

Comment: just brush it with a brush: hairbrush, scrub brush, vacuum brushing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can get dents out of carpet. The key to getting dents out of carpet is to do 3 things: add moisture, dry, and fluff. Keep repeating these steps and eventually the fibers will be back upright.

### Moisture

For this, you can:

- Put ice in the dent and let it melt
- Use a spray bottle to soak the fibers
- Put a damp towel over the dent and use an iron on the steam setting.

### Dry

Dry the dented area with:

- A rag or sponge
- A blow dryer
- The iron if you used the iron on the steam setting

### Fluff

Fluffing can be done with:

- Your fingers
- A fork or a spoon
- Vacuuming over the area